# Passing value from javascript to tapestry java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, tapestry

I'm developing at the moment a website and I want to handle onHover event in tapestry.

For getting the wanted value I use javascript (jQuery) in this way:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
  $(mega).hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

My problem at the moment is that i need to pass the value to the corresponding java file in tapestry, in order to get the pretended values from the db or cache.

Has someone an idea how to do that?

Comment: You need to use ajax. I don't know is there any way to do it with tapestry, but you can always to do that with native javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this with my Observe mixin.

The mixin listens for a clientside event and fires a serverside event passing an optional context value and a configurable list of clientside field values.

- [Live demo](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/observedemo)
- [Observe.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/mixins/Observe.java)
- [Observe.js](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/resources/org/lazan/t5/stitch/mixins/Observe.js)
- [ObserveDemo.tml](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch-demo/src/main/resources/org/lazan/t5/stitch/demo/pages/ObserveDemo.tml)
- [ObserveDemo.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch-demo/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/demo/pages/ObserveDemo.java)

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Answer updated, it's been renamed to `observe` as `onevent` can be read as `one vent`